# What is ".eslintrc.js" in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, eslint

I am using React Native version 0.61.4 where the `.eslintrc.js` file caught my eye.

What is `.eslintrc.js` and what is its use in the React Native?

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Comment: linter for your code base, you decide your lint rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file.eslintrc.js is a configuration file for a tool named ESLINT.

> ESLint is a tool for identifying and reporting on patterns found in
>   ECMAScript/JavaScript code, with the goal of making code more
>   consistent and avoiding bugs. In many ways, it is similar to JSLint
>   and JSHint with a few exceptions:
>
> - ESLint uses Espree for JavaScript parsing.
> - ESLint uses an AST to evaluate patterns in code.
> - ESLint is completely pluggable, every single rule is a plugin and you can add more at runtime.

Source: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started

Answer (score 1):

It is ESlint configuration file.

> ESLint statically analyzes your code to quickly find problems. ... Many
>   problems ESLint finds can be automatically fixed. Fixes are
>   syntax-aware so you won't experience errors introduced by traditional
>   find-and-replace algorithms.

More information about ESlint and configuration you can find here https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to `react-native`, but to [eslint](https://eslint.org/). Which is probably the most popular js linter.

In a nut shell it is a configuration file for [eslint](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring#configuration-file-formats).